# Fibrations whose total spaces are more highly connected than their fibers

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

The (generalized) Hopf fibrations $S^1 \to S^3 \to S^2$, $S^3 \to S^7 \to S^4$ and $S^7 \to S^{15} \to S^8$ have the property that their total spaces are more highly connected than their fibers.

*Are there examples of fibrations $X \to E \to B$ with $X$ a connected finite CW-complex so that $X$ is $(j-1)$-connected but not $j$-connected, and $E$ is $j$-connected for some $j \neq 1, 3, 7$?*

Some thoughts on this:

If we drop the assumption that $X$ is finite, such examples exist for any $j$: the fiber sequence $K(\mathbf Z,j) \to \ast \to K(\mathbf Z,j+1)$ can be realized as such a fibration.

For $X$ finite, however, one can convince oneself that no examples exist unless:

$\bullet$ the number $j$ is odd. Sketch: if $j$ is even, pull the fibration back along a map $S^{j} \to B$ and make use of the polynomial nature of $H^{\ast}(\Omega S^d;\mathbf Q)$,

and

$\bullet$ the Euler characteristic $\chi(X)$ is zero (transfer argument).

But what about $j = 5$ or $j > 7$ odd and $\chi(X) = 0$? Are there any examples?

Comment: Any Lie group $G$, and the universal principal $G$-bundle.

Comment: @OscarRandal-Williams you can't make that work with the $j\neq 1,3,7$ clause.

Comment: ...Unless you take $j=0$, in which case you have the Hopf fibrations missing from the question.

Comment: I see: because a simply-connected compact Lie group has $\pi_3$ nontrivial, right?

Comment: @OscarRandal-Williams Right. In fact J. Lin has shown that any noncontractractible finite H-space with associative mod 2 homology ring has its first nonvanishing homotopy group in degree $1,3$ or $7$. (so  replacing 'Lie group' with 'topological group' yields nothing).